# Function returning before async method done Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

I currently have a function that is called from my router:

router.js:

```
var result = Api.getUser();

console.log("Result: " + result);
```

api.js

```
exports.getUser = function(req, result) {

    request.get({
        uri: URL + '/user/me/',
        headers: {Authorization: 'bearer ' + req.user.accessToken},
        json: true
      }, function(e, r, body) {

        console.log("e: " + e + " body: %j", body);

            if(e) {

                return "{error: true}";

            } else {

                return body;

            }

    });

};
```

The problem I am having is that I am getting the log "Result: undefined" first.

Is there a way to hold the function getUser from returning until the  function for get finishes?

Comment: You're correct, changed in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dealing with asynchronous code. There are a couple ways to solve this problem.

### With A Promise

```
// api.js
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = require('request');
var getP = Promise.promisify(request.get.bind(request));

exports.getUser = function(accessToken) {
  return getP({
    uri: URL + '/user/me/',
    headers: {Authorization: 'bearer ' + accessToken},
    json: true
  }).spread(function(e, r, body) {
    console.log("e: " + e + " body: %j", body);
    if(e) {
      return Promise.reject("{error: true}");
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(body);
    }
  });
};

// main.js
api.getUser(req.user.accessToken)
  .then(console.log.bind(console, "Result: "))
  .catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

### With A Callback

```
// api.js
var request = require('request');

exports.getUser = function(accessToken, callback) {
  request.get({
    uri: URL + '/user/me/',
    headers: {Authorization: 'bearer ' + accessToken},
    json: true
  }, function(e, r, body) {
    console.log("e: " + e + " body: %j", body);
    if(e) {
      callback("{error: true}");
    } else {
      callback(null, body);
    }
  });
};

// main.js
api.getUser(req.user.accessToken, function (err, result) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log("Result: " + result);
});
```

The nice thing about the promise API is that you only ever need to check for errors once, in your final `.catch` handler. In the callback style if you need to keep making additional asynchronous calls then you'll have to keep nesting callbacks and checking `if (err) return console.error(err)` in every single callback.

Comment: A good thorough answer, but why the extra libraries? Wouldn't `new Promise()` suffice? Now that I think about it.. doesn't `request.get()` already return a promise? Are we not double promising here?

Comment: If you're using EcmaScript 6 then yes. `Promise` doesn't exist in es5 :). Also, native es6 promises don't include sugar methods like the call I make to `.spread` after the call to `getP`. After I used bluebird to "promisify" the `request.get` method, bluebird would have noticed that multiple arguments were passed to the callback function you hand to it. Since promises only resolve to one value it would have resolved to an array containing those arguments. `.spread` splits up that array implicitly so you get multiple arguments in your handler instead of that array.

Comment: Also no, I'm pretty sure `request.get` does not return a promise, unless something has changed with the `request` library recently. I know that bluebird's docs even use `request` as an example for promisifcation.

Answer (score 5):

Promises are awesome, I would suggest looking into them. However, a simple callback will do the trick

api:

```
exports.getUser = function(req, result, callback) {
  request.get({
    uri: URL + '/user/me/',
    headers: {Authorization: 'bearer ' + req.user.accessToken},
    json: true
  }, function(e, r, body) {
        if(e) {
            callback({error: true});
        } else {
            callback(body)
        }
    });
};
```

router:

```
var result
Api.getUser(req, result, function (response) {
  result = response
  console.log(result)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't `return` from an async function, you use a callback:

```
exports.getUser = function(req, result, callback) {
   request.get({
    uri: URL + '/user/me/',
    headers: {Authorization: 'bearer ' + req.user.accessToken},
    json: true
  }, function(e, r, body) {
        if(e) {
            callback({error: true});
        } else {
            callback(body);
        }
    });
};

Api.getUser(req, result, function(user) {
    console.log(user);
});
```